# Using the result of a select clause for a where clause to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I have a MySQL database containing 12 columns. I created a dropdown from it using distinct values of the column named 'activity' and the column named 'logdate' which is a datetime.
Like this..

```
<form action="define_activity" id="activityform" method="post">   <!-- Form to select an activity -->
        <select name="activities" id="select1">      <!-- List of activities -->
            <option value="" selected="">Select One</option>
            <option value="NewActivity" id="newactivity"       onclick="newactivity();">New Activity</option>
<?php
foreach($db_found->query("SELECT DISTINCT activity, logdate FROM NetLog ORDER BY activity") as $act) {
echo ("<option value='$act[activity]'>$act[activity] of $act[logdate]</option>");
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name = "Submit" />
</form>
```

This all works great. what I want to do is use the results of the selected option to do another query against the same database that pulls all of the records associated with the selected activity and logdate values. I know how to write the query but I don't know how to find and then use the selected values.

Can someone please show me how to get the selected value from the

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: on form submit the `$_POST['activities']` variable will contain the value selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some changes in your code, I didn't test it, but I think that's going to help you:

```
<?php 

//Returns an associative array with the query result:
    function select($yourSQLQuery){
        //Array with result:
        $result = array();

        //Database conection
        $db = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);

        $stmt = $db->query($yourSQLQuery);

        //This going to save an array with your data:
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        $db = null;

        return $result;
    }

    //*********************************************************************************************
    //Do here your query:
    $result = select("SELECT DISTINCT activity, logdate FROM NetLog ORDER BY activity");
    //*********************************************************************************************


    //Form handler: 
    if($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == "POST"){
        //If the form was submited:

        //Get   selected activity
        if ( isset($_POST['activities']) ) {

    /*Instead of sending your activity you can send the number of the submitted record in $records, then extract activity and logdate and make your query:*/
            $rowNumber = $_POST['activities'];

            //Get your log date:
            $act = $result[$rowNumber]; //if doesn't work try '$rowNumber'
            $activity = $act['activity'];
            $logdate = $act['logdate'];

            //Pull records asocciated with submitted activity:          
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM putHereYourTable WHERE activity = '$activity' AND logdate='$logdate'";
            $records = select($sql);

            //Pulled activities are now in $records 

            //do something with the records that you want. e.g.:
            print_r($records);


        }
    }   
?>

<!-- Your HTML: -->
<form action="define_activity" id="activityform" method="post">   <!-- Form to select an activity -->
        <select name="activities" id="select1">      <!-- List of activities -->
            <option value="" selected="">Select One</option>
            <option value="NewActivity" id="newactivity"       onclick="newactivity();">New Activity</option>
                <?php                   
                    foreach($result as $key => $act) {
                        //Send the number of register instead of $act[activity]:
                        echo ("<option value='$key'>$act[activity] of $act[logdate]</option>");
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name = "Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It got me closest to the answer I needed. If I get this thing finished I'll try and remember to post what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the form first.

```
<form action="define_activity" id="activityform" method="post">
```

You need to submit to a valid page in your action param. So if 'define_activity' is not a valid URL (ie: not handled by htaccess) then you need to either A) use the same script/file your using or B) create another page to handle the data.

I would do this:

```
<form action="process.php" id="activityform" method="post">
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['activities']) ) {
    // do something with the submitted data
    $selectedValue = $_POST['activities'];
}
```

Now you have the selected value. You have also any other value that is submitted in the form, $_POST['othervalue'].

For a clear view of what is sent, dump it.

```
die('<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>');
```

or you could use var_dump: `die( var_dump($_POST) );`

Answer (score 0):

Keith,

You have to remember that web applications work in a client server environment over the HTTP protocol.

After your page is done loading the first time, the php script is basically done executing. In order for more code to run, another request needs to be sent to the server. This happens when you either:

a) submit a form or click a link that sends a new http request to the page

b) make some javascript send a new HTTP request to the page.

Since you're just getting started, lets assume you just want that form to send the new request off to the page.

So at the top of your php script, just add this statement:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

As you visit the page that is running the script both with and without clicking the submit post button, you will be able to see the various request parameters show up based on your form post. One of those params will be 'activity' .. just throw an if statement checking to see if that parameter is present, then run your query inside that if statement, using the value of 'activity'

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['activities'])) {
//do your query here..
}
```